# How do I keep middle div on top when screen estate shrinks?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have three divs and I would like them to be laid out in a row when the screen estate permits, but if not, the middle div should stay on top and the left and right should move below it. Given the reply to a similar question about Bootstrap ([How to push the middle div on top in small screen in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825040/how-to-push-the-middle-div-on-top-in-small-screen-in-bootstrap)) it looks like it is doable, but I would like to see the actual CSS for this.

```
<div class="left">
LEFT
</div>
<div class="middle">
THIS IS A LONG TEXT
</div>
<div class="right">
RIGHT
</div>
```

Comment: flex, order and some media queries should work in a modern browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the actual CSS on how to do this with CSS Grid and Media Queries.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "middle" "left" "right";
}

.left {
  grid-area: left;
}

.middle {
  grid-area: middle;
}

.right {
  grid-area: right;
}

@media (min-width:600px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-areas: "left middle right";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="left">
    LEFT
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    THIS IS A LONG TEXT
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    RIGHT
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to learn about CSS Grid, this is a good place to start: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The additional resource you linked also helped me out with all further questions I had.